# about visible digital signatures

Tags: itext, digital-signature

Given an input pdf file with visible digital signatures, I would like to obtain a new pdf file that preserves the visual representation of the signatures as graphical objects but not longer as signatures fields.

I have done that with a tool (see the input and the output files) but I would like to know how to do it with iText.

input: [input.pdf](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0tz2oVFqBpZT0RGcFc0Y0oxNG8/view?usp=sharing)

output: [output.pdf](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0tz2oVFqBpZbld3UkFTUGhGcEU/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Try to insert relevant information from the pdf to your answer. All external links or files may not be accessible by all users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please be aware that signatures done well (using a certificate from a CA that is member of CDS or AATL) can be verified so that you can test for (1) "integrity", (2) "authentication", and (3) "non-repudiation". By throwing away the signature fields, you lose all that information and nobody will be able to know if the document was changed after signing (1), nor who signed the document (2). The signer can always claim that he never signed that document (3) because anyone could have created the visual representation of his signature.

By removing the signature you will create a copy without an actual signature, similar to what you'd have if you printed a document that is digitally signed. You'll be throwing away important information by removing the actual digital signature, keeping only the visual appearance.

This being said, you are asking for something very simple: you want to *flatten* a PDF file. This is shown in the [FlattenSignature](http://itextpdf.com/sandbox/acroforms/FlattenSignature) example. Check the file [output_no_longer_signed.pdf](http://itextpdf.com/sites/default/files/output_no_longer_signed.pdf) and you'll notice that it looks exactly like your output.pdf.

The code to achieve this is very simple:

```
public void manipulatePdf(String src, String dest)
    throws DocumentException, IOException {
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);
    PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileOutputStream(dest));
    stamper.setFormFlattening(true);
    stamper.close();
}
```

Comment: Digital signatures by themselves do not provide evidence of authenticity and nonrepudiation. For this it is necessary to consider some additional requirements as for example, among others, the validity and "trust" of the signing certificate and the certificates chain.

An example of use case may be when you need to get watermarked copies of the "original" digitally signed document. The marks of this "copy" may contain the IP, datetime, username, etc.

Thanks for the quick answer.

Comment: OK, watermarks would break the signatures and if you merely need a copy, the use case is acceptable. Digital signatures done well using a certificate from a CA that is a member of CDS or AATL provide authenticity and non-repudiation. If they didn't, CAs wouldn't have a business...

Comment: The validity of a digital signature depends of the context. For example, in Europe, instead of the AATL must be used the EU Trusted Lists (TSL). More info [here](http://ec.europa.eu/digital-agenda/en/eu-trusted-lists-certification-service-providers).

Comment: Yes, Europe has a way to introduce its own rules. See also https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wHmP58D0cRY

Answer (score 0):

For me Bruno's answer didn't work.
I needed to call `setGenerateAppearances(true)` the be able to see the flattened signatures

```
public void flatPdf(String src, String dest) throws DocumentException, IOException {
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);
    PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileOutputStream(dest));
    AcroFields fields = stamper.getAcroFields();
    fields.setGenerateAppearances(true);
    stamper.setFormFlattening(true);
    stamper.close();
}
```

with: iText 5.5.13